# Protecting email addresses if their hashes are publicly avaliable

Tags: hash

I am working on a project, where user email address hashes will be available publicly, and I need to prevent them from being quickly discovered by spammers.

The main idea of the undertaking is to give anyone who already knows the email addresses an easy way to find users by them, but make it difficult to discover emails by simple enumeration of possible alternatives.

What I thought about is using BCrypt or PBKDF2 to create the hashes, and use salt to create hashes where the sum of the bytes in the first half equals the sum of the bytes in the second half.

Here's what the algorithm could look like:

```
    static byte[] GenerateMagicSignature(string text)
    {
        long id = 0;
        const int nParts = 2;
        while (true)
        {
            var key = BitConverter.GetBytes(id);

            for (long i = 0; i < id+1; i++)
            {
                var dd = new HMACSHA256(key);//replaced new encoding....
                key = dd.ComputeHash(key); 
            }

            var b=new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(text,key,10000);

            var sig=b.GetBytes(32);
            id++;
            var pts = SplitIntoPartsAndSum(sig, nParts);

            int val = pts[0];

            bool wrong = false;
            for (int i = 1; i < pts.Length; i++)
            {
                if (val!=pts[i])
                {
                    wrong = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (wrong)
            {
                continue;
            }


            return sig;
        }
    }

    static int[] SplitIntoPartsAndSum(byte[] data, int parts)
    {
        var sums=new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < parts; i++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            var start = i*data.Length/parts;
            var end = (i + 1)*data.Length/parts;
            if (i==parts-1)
            {
                end = data.Length;
            }
            for (int j = start; j < end; j++)
            {
                sum += data[j];
            }

            sums.Add(sum);
        }

        return sums.ToArray();
    }
```

The average hashing time for a known email address with these settings is around 1 minute on a single CPU. Which right now can be divided by 5000 cuda cores, if I understand this stuff correctly (or is the use of PBKDF2 going to significantly reduce that number?).

My question is: is doing this a good idea, or do I have to re-think the whole thing? My goal is not to make the email addresses fully protected, but make it more difficult for the attacker to get them than, say, by sending queries to facebook and checking if it knows those emails or not.

Comment: Maybe I am too tired to understand, but how do hashes of e-mails have anything to do with spammers? The salt should be random per user or even per mail.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, if I set the hash randomly, the emails won't be discoverable by hashes for those, who already know them. Since the hashes will be public, everyone can access them, including spammers, and I'm thinking on how to prevent that from happening

Comment: Do you mean "emails" or "email addresses"?

Comment: I guess I really don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I mean, email addresses. Let's say, I've got email `myemail@example.com` and a few hundred thousand more like it. I want to compute a hash of it (in this case, `GojBUqM8qndfuL3e5wBejyCRLA9I2o+jMMwAhs3E7vo=`) and make it publicly available. If you know the email, you should be able to easily discover it, if not, it should be hard. Is this going to work?

Comment: I guess, I'm looking for a hash function, which would be hard to compute and as GPU resistant as possible

Comment: What's wrong with bcrypt? Doesn't that meet your needs?

Comment: @NeilSmithline The OP is looking for an encrypted index. Bcrypt by its very nature prevents encrypted index lookup (otherwise known as a rainbow table).

Comment: I'm not sure that's right @Aron. The OP is suggesting that bcrypt works as they've described and are curious if this is secure enough. I think they are trying to create a lookup table where calculating the index to lookup is computationally very costly, but they have an unusual way of doing it.

Comment: @neilsmithline by definition the bcrypt algo includes a salt. Without the salt, it isn't the bcrypt algo. A salt breaks the pigeon hole, which is the basis of fast lookup of the original message. http://crypto.stanford.edu/~eujin/papers/secureindex/

Comment: @Aron - I believe that that requires a "secret key" while the OP wants something that will work without a secret key. And the OP uses something that they call salt that is calculated using a [POW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof-of-work_system) scheme that makes no sense to me whatsoever as it will sometimes be very costly to calculate and other times cheap.

Comment: All that said @Aron, I think we really need the OP to chime in here. The question just doesn't seem clear.

Comment: @NeilSmithline as far as I can see the OP is trying to create a trap door (hash) function with a specified (high) cost. Then asking if the function he came up with is such a case and if it has any security issues. As Neil said the strengthening part is simply POW. But due to pigeon hole theory, there are many solutions to your POW and hence many salts.

Comment: What is wrong with rate limiting a client or applying delays before you answer a search query? That'd prevent brute-force enumeration, wouldn't it?

Comment: @SteveDL the OP wants to make the client do the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email addresses are very often built off of easy to construct, common patterns with public data - first initial plus last name @ company, first name dot last name @ company, etc. etc. etc.

Further, many actual email addresses have been leaked, and several sets of attackers are going to have stolen or purchased large lists of email addresses to try as well.

Therefore, attackers have a much, much smaller keyspace than when attacking passwords.

I'll address PBKDF2 in specific; assuming your clients have powerful, modern 64-bit machines, they can still only use one core to hash one email address (their own); [Hashcat](http://hashcat.net/hashcat/) probably has one of the most optimized sets of code available for CPU, and [oclHashcat](http://hashcat.net/hashcat/) likewise for GPU.

Assuming a PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-1 style setup (i.e. SHA-1 is the base hash), then you can expect a single serious modern 8-GPU box to crunch passwords 1500 to 2500 times faster than x64 code running on a fairly serious modern CPU; the advantage only grows if your users have out of date hardware, inexpensive hardware, low power hardware, or mobile devices.

Even at, say, 2000 times faster, the attacker averages 0.03 seconds to run a test on an email it took a client one minute to generate.

PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-512 would reduce the attacker's advantage, but you're still in a losing game, since an attacker can spin up their GPU's and leave the machine to try email patterns for two and a half million seconds (30 days) easily, paying only an electric bill and the loss of that machine for other actions.

Alternately, spammers may simply dedicate spare CPU time, which they probably have plenty of, to validating their email lists against your email list.  It's even free if they're using other people's computers (i.e. a botnet)!